# (REOPENED) Reopen the question on boss and HR not responding to employee who resigned from client location

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

This question [I work at client site, and have resigned in probation period. How can I handle the situation?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/99549/3192) was closed with the reason:

> Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies should be directed to your manager or HR department. Questions that address only a specific company or position are of limited use to future visitors. Questions seeking legal advice should be directed to legal professionals.

This close reason makes no sense, and the question should be reopened.

- OP has already contacted the manager and the HR, and part of her issue is that they aren't responding. Telling her to direct the question to the manager and the HR is not especially helpful.
- The presence of the word 'legal' doesn't automatically make it a question seeking legal advice. Questions asking for facts of law are not off-topic. OP's question is whether leaving the company without returning the laptop will create a legal issue. It is a fact of law that can be answered by any person with a reasonable "common sense" awareness of the law — not just an HR professional.
- An employee working from a client location, resigning in probation period, and having issues communicating with management and HR working from "home ground" is a reasonably common situation. I have faced this situation myself at one of my previous jobs.

Of course, I am aware that the close reason banner is boilerplate, but nonetheless, the question is not company-specific and does not ask for any legal advice. (Disclaimer: As you might have noticed, I have answered the question without referring to the company policy or any specific detail of any law.)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know how to reopen the question. But i totally agree with all your facts stated in points. That is exactly my problem and it is not company specific. It is a very generic issue which can be faced by anyone

Comment: I'd suggest editing it into shape and at least identifying the core question in bold or in a tl;dr. That should help get the reopens. The core questions seems on-topic and answerable to me but it could be trimmed down to improve the quality. You may also want to drop "*Will there be any legal issue?*" from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a further [edit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/99549/6) from [IDrinkAndIKnowThings](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/16/idrinkandiknowthings), the question has now been reopened. Thanks.